# How to compare two array and get different elements by swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I search in Stack, but I don't find my answer.
I have two arrays and I want to get different elements of them.

ex:

```
var a:[String] = ["a","b","c"]
var b:[String] = ["a","b","d"]
//a compare with b and get ["c","d"] 


var c:[String] = ["a","b","c","d"]
var d:[String] = ["a","b","c"]   
//c compare with d and get ["d"]
```

Sorry I'm beginner of swift.
And how to do this idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Solution with array : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45861222/6479530

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [`symmetricDifference`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/2853711-symmetricdifference):

```
// ["d"]
Set(["a", "b", "c"]).symmetricDifference(["a", "b", "c", "d"])
```

> Returns a new set with the elements that are either in this set or in the given sequence, but not in both.

Comment: Thanks All, let me learn this function.

Comment: And if performance is an issue, ensure that you're making the larger array into the Set, and using the smaller one as the argument